# How to simplify this XNOR expression?

Tags: logic

```
**Show that AB' + C(A'B' + AB) = AB' + AC + B'C**
```

I understand that the expression in brackets is the same as A XNOR B, but have no idea how to proceed towards the final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$AB'+C(A'B'+AB)=AB'+A'B'C+ABC\\=B'(A+A'C)+ABC\\=B'(A+C)+ABC\ \ (*)\\=AB'+B'C+ABC\\=AB'+C(B'+AB)\\=AB'+C(B'+A)\ \ \ \ (*)$

$(*)$ Absorption Law: $X+X'Y=X+Y$

Comment: Thanks so much!